# PHP Style Guideline

Tags: php, coding-style

What is the best styling way of writing such a code in PHP?

```
$result = $this->funcA(param1, param2, param3, ...)->funcB(...)->funcC(...)
```

Also, what if the arguments are super long? How and where should you break them into multiple lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I like:

```
$result = $this->funcAaAaA ( param1, param2, param3, ... )
               ->funcBb    ( 'a',    'b' )
               ->funcCcc   ( "word", TRUE )
```

Lot's of redundant whitespaces, yes. But it gives a very clear look and is easy to follow on a glance because logical blocks become very clear.

There are a few other things:

- only one single class per file
- decide for a spelling case in names for class and method names *and stay with that*. I myself use smallCamelCase.
- opening curly brackets on the line of the opening language construct, *except when opening a method on first level or a class*
- indentation of 2 blanks per level, most modern editors allow to enter tabs and have them converted into 2 spaces
- in-code documentation preceding every class, method and function, so that you can use `phpdoc` or the like
- use namespaces, but not too exessively
- use what visibility selectors php offers (private, public, ...), although php is pretty dull in that, often you are forced to make things public, whyever. Nevertheless note them down.
- use single quotes for 'technical identifiers' and double quotes for "human readable text", typically for output.
- use class constants wherever possible
- static class methods often allow cleaner code and save you from instanciating redundant objects
- use upper case spelling for constants and language contructs like `TRUE` and `FALSE`
- prevent string concatenations using the `period operator`, use `sprintf()` instead
- put a clear comment header at the top of each file stating the name of the file, its purpose, the author(s), the license. Use the same structure of header throughout *all* files, even across language borders (sql files or js or the like)

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.funcalls.php), Using fluent application programming interfaces often leads to many concatenated function calls. Those calls may be split onto several lines. When doing this, all subsequent lines are indented by `4 spaces` and begin with the `"->"` arrow.

Example:

```
<?php

$result=$this->funcA(param1, param2, ...)
    ->funcB(23, 42)
    ->funcC();
?>
```

To support readability, parameters in subsequent calls to the same function/method may be aligned by parameter name.

Example:

```
<?php

$this->callSomeFunction('param1',     'second',        true);
$this->callSomeFunction('parameter2', 'third',         false);
$this->callSomeFunction('3',          'verrrrrrylong', true);
?>
```

The same applies not only for parameter variables, but also for nested function calls and for arrays

Comment: okay thanks, and how about the arguments for the functions?

Comment: And also, why not use @arkascha method? It looks cleaner with all the -> lining up

Comment: I didn't said that. If you want, you can use

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these guidelines for you PHP code http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/